# How do I make the text appear under the center of the recipe image and be an equal distance from each other with css?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to create a website with recipes, so I put images of the recipes, with the name of the recipe underneath, but the problem is that they are not landing in the center beneath the image. They are the same distance apart, but I can't get each text to go under the image in the center. How would I do this? I would suggest viewing the result of the code in full view because I have not coded the website to work properly when the window is minimized. Also, you won't see the images because they are files on my computer.

```css
<style>
body{
    background: rgb(239,239,239);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

a:nth-child(2) {
margin-left: 300px;
}

    
nav{
    height: 120px;
    length:relative;
    background: rgb(250,131,131);
}

.header{
overflow:hidden;
background-color: white;
padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header-right a {
float:right;
color:black;
text-align:center;
padding:12px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Paprika', cursive;
font-size:18px;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius:4px;
font-size:14px;
}

.header a.logo{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
float:left;
font-family:"Poppins", cursive;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
letter-spacing: 10px;
}


.header-right a:hover{
background-color: rgb(248,248,248);
color:black;
}

.header a.active {
background-color: rgb(225,225,225);
color:black;
}

.header-right input[type=text] {
float:right;
padding:6px;
margin-top:9px;
margin-right:16px;
font-size:17px;
}

.latest{
font-family: "Pavanam", snas-serif;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing:8px;
}

.simple{
font-family: "Pavanam", snas-serif;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing:8px;
font-size: 12px;
margin-top:300px;
}

hr{
width:10%;
}
.doball:hover, .cookie:hover, .cake:hover, .snacks:hover{

transform:scale(1.2);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
a:nth-child(2) {
margin-left: 300px;
}
.choccook{
height:150px;
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:50px;
width:230px;
height:230px;

}

.oreocak, .coffcake, .granbar,.banbread, .cinnroll{
height:150px;
margin-left:1.5px;
margin-bottom:50px;
width:230px;
height:230px;
object-fit:cover;

}

.choccook:hover, .oreocak:hover, .coffcake:hover, .granbar:hover, .banbread:hover, .cinnroll:hover{
opacity:50%;
}


.recip{
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:-50px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:"Pavanam", cursive;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
letter-spacing: 5px;

}
.recipnameone,.recipnametwo, .recipnamethree, .recipnamefour, .recipnamefive{
margin-left:100px;
}
.doball, .cookie, .cake, .snacks{

margin-left:30px;
margin-bottom:100px;
width:80px;
height:80px;
object-fit:cover;
transition: 0.5s ease;
border-radius:50%;
}

.categories{
margin-left:550px;
}

.circone{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:"Pavanam", cursive;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
letter-spacing:3px;

}

.categnames{
margin-left:40px;
margin-top:-120px;
}

.circtwo, .circthree, .circthree, .circfour{
margin-left:55px;



.recipnamefive{
font-size:13px;
}

.recippics{
margin-top:-80px;
}


</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Bake It Simple</title>


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Paprika&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pavanam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<a href="#" class="logo">BAKE IT SIMPLE</a>
<div class="header-right">
<a href="aboutbakingpage.html">About</a>
<a href="#">Recipes</a>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
</div>


<h3 class="latest">LATEST RECIPES</h3>
<hr>
<div class="recippics">
<img class="choccook" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/cookies.jpg" href="#"></img>   
<img class="oreocak" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/oreocake.jpg" href="#"></img>
<img class="coffcake" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/coffeecake.jpg" href="#"></img>
<img class="granbar" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/granolabars.png" href="#"></img>
<img class="banbread" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/bananabread.jpg" href="#"></img>
<img class="cinnroll" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/cinnamonrolls.jpg" href="#"></img>
</div>

<p class="recip"><span class="recipname"> C.C. COOKIES</span> <span class="recipnameone"> OREO CAKE</span> <span class="recipnametwo"> COFFEE CAKE</span> <span class="recipnamethree"> GRANOLA BARS</span> <span class="recipnamefour"> BANANA BREAD</span> <span class="recipnamefive"> CINNAMON ROLLS</span></p>


<h3 class="simple">SO SIMPLE, IT TASTES BETTER</h3>
</hr>



<div class="categories">
<img class="doball" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/doughcirc.jpg" href="#"></img>
<img class="cookie" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/cookies.jpg" href="#"></img>   
<img class="cake" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/oreocake.jpg" href="#"></img>
<img class="snacks" src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/granolabars.png" href="#"></img>
<div class="categnames">
<p class="circone"> DOUGHS <span class="circtwo"> COOKIES</span> <span class="circthree"> CAKES</span> <span class="circfour"> SNACKS</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your recipe names separate from your recipe images, which is difficult (if not impossible) to get everything to align. It would be easier to associate the names with the images in separate blocks. I set each block to float left to show how to align the text, but you could use flex to setup how your recipes will work on different screen sizes.

```css
.recipe {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 150px;
}

.recipe img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.recipe p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="recippics">
  <div class="recipe">
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/cookies.jpg">
    <p>C.C. COOKIES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe">
    <img  src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/oreocake.jpg">
    <p>OREO CAKE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe">
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/Pranavi.Kedari/Pictures/coffeecake.jpg">
    <p>COFFEE CAKE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For future questions, you don’t need to include all of the unused stuff like the header CSS. Just include enough to show the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't think about that before!